# Need help getting for loop to iterate correctly

Tags: python-3.2

I am working on this for homework, and I have most of this done my problem is there is something wrong in one of the for loops as the display I get is only one line when it should be a line for every value in the range 50,000 - 60,000 with a step value of 50.

```
    def computeTax(status, taxableIncome):
        print("Taxable Income/" + "\t" + "Single/" + "\t" + "Married Joint/" + \
              "\t" + "Married Separate/" + "  " + "Head of Household")
        for taxableIncome in range(50000, 60001, 50):
            for status in range(1, 5, 1):
              if (status == 1):    #tax calculation for single person
                 tax1 = 8350 * .10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 + \
                       (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25
                 tax1 = round(tax1,0)
              if (status == 2):   #tax calculation for married file jointly
                 tax2 = 16700 * .10 + (67900 - 16700) * 0.15 + \
                        (taxableIncome - 67900) * 0.15
                 tax2 = round(tax2,0)
              if (status == 3):   #tax calculation for married file separately
                 tax3 = 8350 * .10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 + \
                       (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25
                 tax3 = round(tax3,0)
              if (status == 4): #tax calculation for head of household
                 tax4 = 11950 * .10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 + \
                       (taxableIncome - 45500) * 0.25
                 tax4 = round(tax4,0)
         print(str(tax1) + "\t" + str(tax2) + "\t" + str(tax3) + "\t" + str(tax4))
        return (status, taxableIncome)


    computeTax(range(1, 5, 1),range(50000, 60001, 50))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with python, but do you have to define code blocks like you would with PHP?
EG

```
if (status == 1):    #tax calculation for single person
{                 
tax1 = 8350 * .10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 + \
                       (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25
                 tax1 = round(tax1,0)
}
```

Like I said; not familiar with Python, but I thought I might have an answer for you; if I'm completely off then sorry and good luck.

Comment: I figured it out, I had the print statement under the whole function rather than just with the second for loop(what was actually telling the print to display) and once I indented properly everything worked fine.
Thanks for your help though!